# Data not showing in DataGridView when button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am making a small Windows Form Application using VB and I am trying to view the records from my SUPPLIERS table. When I press the View Suppliers button it does not work. I have another table called PARTS in which I can view the parts by pressing the View Parts button. It is strange as it works fine for the PARTS table on a different form but not for the SUPPLIERS table on the current form. This is my code for the button. Is there anything I am forgetting.

// Code for showing current table records

```
Private Sub viewSupplier_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
   viewSupplier.Click
   Dim ds As New DataSet
   ds = Form1.populateDS1()
   DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("DT_SUPPLIERS")
End Sub
```

// Code for other table which works fine

```
Private Sub viewButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
       viewButton.Click
       Dim ds As New DataSet
       ds = Form1.populateDS()
       DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("DT_PART")
 End Sub

// DS AND DS1 Code
Public Function populateDS() As DataSet
        ds = New DataSet
        Dim sql As String
        Dim da As OracleDataAdapter
        sql = "SELECT * from PART"
        da = New OracleDataAdapter(sql, Connect())
        da.Fill(ds, "DT_PART")
        con.Close()
        Return ds
    End Function

    Public Function populateDS1() As DataSet
        ds = New DataSet
        Dim sql As String
        Dim da As OracleDataAdapter
        sql = "SELECT * from SUPPLIER"
        da = New OracleDataAdapter(sql, Connect())
        da.Fill(ds, "DT_SUPPLIER")
        con.Close()
        Return ds
    End Function
```

Comment: Show the code for `populateDS1()`... as it must be different from `populateDS()`.

Comment: @Zaggler I have updated the code above with the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table name is wrong... Change this...

```
 DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("DT_SUPPLIERS")
```

**To this...** (drop the "s")

```
 DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("DT_SUPPLIER")
```